# Using a constant IV with single-block encryption

Tags: cryptography, aes, initialization-vector

I have lots of small secrets that I want to store encrypted in a database. The database client will have the keys, and the database server will not deal with encryption and decryption. All of my secrets are 16 bytes or less, which means just one block when using AES. I'm using a constant IV (and key) to make the encryption deterministic and my reason for doing deterministic encryption is to be able to easily query the database using ciphertext and making sure the same secret is not stored twice (by making the column UNIQUE). As far as I can see there should be no problem doing this, as long as the key is secret. But I want to be sure: Am I right or wrong? In case I'm wrong, what attacks could be done?

BTW: Hashes are quite useless here, because of a relatively small number of possible plaintexts. With a hash it would be trivial to obtain the original plaintext.

Answer (score 10):

An ideal cipher, for messages of length *n* bits, is a permutation of the *2<sup>n</sup>* sequences of *n* bits, chosen at random in the *2<sup>n</sup>!* such permutations. The "key" is the description of which permutation was chosen.

A secure block cipher is supposed to be indistinguishable from an ideal cipher, with *n* being the block size. For AES, *n=128* (i.e. 16 bytes). AES is supposed to be a secure block cipher.

If all your secrets have length exactly 16 bytes (or less than 16 bytes, with some padding convention to unambiguously extend them to 16 bytes), then an ideal cipher is what you want, and AES "as itself" should be fine. With common AES implementations, which want to apply padding and process arbitrarily long streams, you can get a single-block encryption by asking for ECB mode, or CBC mode with an all-zero IV.

All the issues about IV, and why chaining modes such as CBC were needed in the first place, come from multi-block messages. AES encrypts 16-byte messages (no more, no less): chaining modes are about emulating an ideal cipher for longer messages. If, in your application, all messages have length exactly 16 bytes (or are shorter, but you add padding), then you just need the "raw" AES; and a fixed IV is a close enough emulation of raw AES.

Note, though, the following:

- If you are storing encrypted elements in a database, and require uniqueness for the whole lifetime of your application, then your secret key is long-lived. Keeping a secret key secret for a long time can be a hard problem. For instance, long-lived secret keys need some kind of storage (which resists to reboots). How do you manage dead hard disks ? Do you destroy them in an acid-filled cauldron ?
- Encryption ensures *confidentiality*, not *integrity*. In most security models, attackers can be active (i.e., if the attacker can *read* the database, he can probably *write* into it too). Active attacks open up a full host of issues: for instance, what could happen if the attacker swaps some of your secrets within the database ? Or alters some randomly ? Encryption is, as always, the easy part (not that it is really "easy", but it is much easier than the rest of the job).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was exactly what I wanted to know! Don't have the reputation to vote you up, I hope someone else does. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the assembly is publicly available, or can become so, your key and IV can be discovered by using Reflector to expose the source code that uses it. That would be the main problem with this, if the data really were secret. It is possible to obfuscate MSIL, but that just makes it harder to trace through; it still has to be computer-consumable, so you can't truly encrypt it.

Comment: The assembly is not publicly available. My main question here is whether it is safe to use a constant IV. If anyone gets access to the whole database, is it easier to crack the encryption than if I use a unique (random) IV per row?

Comment: It is no more or less safe than any method using a random IV, the one exception being that if they know for one, they know for all. You (and any attacker) must know two secrets - the key and IV - to decrypt an AES ciphertext encrypted with same. If you use a constant IV, you can hide it the same way you would your key. If you use a random IV, you must somehow include the IV with the ciphertext so it can be used to decrypt that message; that means the two secrets become the key, and how you include the IV in the ciphertext. That second secret is now much less difficult to discover.

Comment: Ok, then it is as I thought. Thanks for the answers! :-)

Comment: @tryeng The IV is immaterial - with only a single block and a fixed key, you may as well use ECB, as Thomas recommends, and skip the IV altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The static IV would make your implementation vulnerable to frequency attacks.  See [For AES CBC encryption, whats the importance of the IV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641720/for-aes-cbc-encryption-whats-the-importance-of-the-iv)