# AES encryption using Iv

Tags: java

What's the best way to append a Iv to a encrypted message?

Can I append it by doing a base 64 encoding out of obtained Iv and use a delimiter to append it with a bqse64 encrypted message? Or suggest some good and secure ideas.

Comment: You should read up on the basics yourself (base64 is **not** encryption). Ask your question when you have a specific problem

Comment: Puelo ... I know that base64 is not an encryption. I do know the complete functionality of AES. The problem is that once I get the encrypted message , to decrypt the same I need the Iv that was used as part of encryption. So , how do I store this Iv securely is my question .

Answer (score 0):

You can find some excellent answers here: [AES encryption how to transport IV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804574/aes-encryption-how-to-transport-iv?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Quote:

> There is no security hole by sending the IV in cleartext - this is
>   similar to storing the salt for a hash in plaintext: As long as the
>   attacker has no control over the IV/salt, and as long as it is random,
>   there is no problem.

So it is up to you how to want to transport/store the IV, as long as it is random and not controlled by an attacker. There is no established optimal way.